# How to cancel routeChange or browser reload when form is incomplete?

Tags: angularjs

There are scenarios like:

1. Browser reload,
2. Closing tab
3. closing browser
4. Route change (e.g. clicking on links)
5. Browsers back button was clicked. or history.go(-1). 3 fingers swipe on Macbooks.

that we would want to prevent if the user has filled some sort of form or is in middle of the writing.

I have written this code which works fine but its absolutely not useful if I cant implement it on several textfields. Currently it only check if we are at #/write url. It doesnt check any inputs.

Whats the angular way to deal with this? Whats the best way to check the target textfield. Is a directive the solution?
something like:

```
<input type="text" warningOnLeave ng-model="title"/>
```

or

```
<form warningOnLeave name="myForm">...</form>


 $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, current, previous){

    console.log(current);
    console.log(previous);
    // Prevent route change behaviour
    if(previous == 'http://localhost/#/write' && current != previous){
        var answer = confirm ("You have not saved your text yet. Are you sure you want to leave?");
        if (!answer)
            event.preventDefault();     
    }

});




/** 
   Prevent browser behaviour
*/

window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    if(document.URL == 'http://localhost/#/write'){
        e = e || window.event;

        // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
        if (e) {
            e.returnValue = 'You have not saved your text yet.';
        }

        // For Safari
        return 'You have not saved your text yet.';
    }
    else
        return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Forms](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3aform.FormController) in Angular have the `$dirty`/`$pristine` properties that mark if the user has/hasn't interacted with the form controlls, and the accompanying method `$setPristine()`. I would base the desired functionality on this feature. Consider:

```
<form name="theForm" ng-controller="TheCtrl" ...>
```

This puts the form in the scope of the controller, under the given name. Then something like:

```
controller("TheCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, current, previous) {
        if( $scope.theForm.$dirty ) {
            // here goes the warning logic
        }
    });
});
```

Do not forget to call `$scope.theForm.$setPristine()` where appropriate (i.e. after submitted or cleared).

For the window unload case, you will have to watch the `$dirty` flag. So in the previous controller:

```
$scope.$watch("theForm.$dirty", function(newval) {
    window.myGlobalDirtyFlag = newval;
});
```

You have to do this because the `window.onbeforeunload` event does not have access to the scope of the form. Then, in the global section of your app:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    if( window.myGlobalDirtyFlag === true ) {
        // warning logic here
    }
};
```

Again, you may want to clear the global dirty flag when the scope is destroyed, so in the controller:

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
    window.myGlobalDirtyFlag = false;
});
```